# How to fix SpEL expression in @PreAuthorize?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Hi all Spring Security experts!

I've been developing a number of microservices and faced a security issue.

In my projects, I use authentication/authorization through JWT.

Could anybody answer me what can lead to a runtime exception

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-02T00:40:38.211+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Failed to evaluate expression 'authentication.name == userId'",
    "path": ".../2"
}
```

in this piece of code:

```
@PreAuthorize("authentication.name == userId")
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
ResponseEntity<String> get(@PathVariable final String userId);
```

I also tried it with `@PreAuthorize("principal.username == #userId")`but got the same exception meanwhile `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_COMRADE_MAJOR')")` behaves correctly.

What should I change to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try `#userId == authentication.principal.username`? Like shown in section 33 on this page: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: You are getting a stack trace on the server console that will explain specifically what the problem is (most likely, that `userId` cannot be resolved because it needs the `#` Andreas mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.name")
ResponseEntity<String> get(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

See for example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2376